# PHP: using variables in associative arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

it seems I missed something important about arrays in PHP.

What's wrong with this:

```
var $condition = array('Status.name = ' => 'PUBLISHED');
var $paginate = array('conditions' => $condition );
```

this works just fine:

```
var $paginate = array('conditions' => array('Status.name = ' => 'PUBLISHED' ));
```

Comment: Do you get an error, or what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: You forgot to describe the context of the code; it can be easily guessed from what you write, but it still a guess. It would have been better if you would have explicitly said if you are reporting a class code; differently, you will get many answers telling you the code is not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why the `var` keyword? Normally you wouldn't need this - unless these are fields on an object?. If so, you will need to reference them using $this. One of the following examples should work for you:

```
$condition = array('Status.name = ' => 'PUBLISHED');
$paginate = array('conditions' => $condition );
```

or

```
var $condition = array('Status.name = ' => 'PUBLISHED');
var $paginate = array('conditions' => $this->condition );
```

Without seeing more of the code, it is hard for me to say with certainty which one applies to you and/or if this will solve your problem. Hopefully it's pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

The `var` part suggests me that you are defining a class. In that case, you cannot initialize an object  variable with the content of another one; you can only initialize them with constants (which includes array).

```
<?php
  class test {
    var $test1 = array('test_11' => 10);
    var $test2 = array('test21' => $test1); // Error
  }
?>
```

If you need to initialize the content of a variable with the content of another one, then use the constructor.

```
<?php
  class test {
    function test() {
      $this->test1 = array('test_11' => 10);
      $this->test2 = array('test21' => $this->test1);
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The var keyword is for declaring the class member variable and not for non-class variables.

The var keyword is supported in PHP5, albeit deprecated.

But for the *var* keyword, everything works as expected and we see the following when we dump the paginate array:

```
array(1) {
  ["conditions"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Status.name = "]=>
    string(9) "PUBLISHED"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, both do not work. However, when i remove the var keyword from variables, both work perfectly well. Var keyword was used in php4.